# Listen to changes within a DIV and act accordingly

Tags: jquery

I have a function that grabs an XML document and transforms it according to an XSL document.  It then places the result into a div with the id `laneconfigdisplay`.  What I want to do is, separate to the transformation logic, setup a jQuery change event for that div so I can tell when it has changed, and run some jQuery code.

I have tried the following, but it does not work!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#laneconfigdisplay').change(function() {
        alert('woo');
    });
    //Do XML / XSL transformation here
});

<!-- HTML code here -->
<div id="laneconfigdisplay"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can opt to create your own custom events so you'll still have a clear separation of logic.

Bind to a custom event:

```
$('#laneconfigdisplay').bind('contentchanged', function() {
  // do something after the div content has changed
  alert('woo');
});
```

In your function that updates the div:

```
// all logic for grabbing xml and updating the div here ..
// and then send a message/event that we have updated the div
$('#laneconfigdisplay').trigger('contentchanged'); // this will call the function above
```

Comment: For some reason, $('#laneconfigdisplay').bind('contentchanged', function()... does not work. Using $(document).on('contentchanged', '#laneconfigdisplay', function(), as suggested by @AlbatrossCafe works.

Comment: yes , if we create that div in dynamically , we need to use this code$(document).on('contentchanged', '#laneconfigdisplay', function()..

Answer (score 14):

The `change` event is limited to `input`, `textarea` & and `select`.

See http://api.jquery.com/change/ for more information.

Comment: Ah... Doh.  How Do I listen for changes within a div then... Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 11):

http://api.jquery.com/change/

change does only work on input form elements.

you could just trigger a function after your XML / XSL transformation or make a listener:

```
var html = $('#laneconfigdisplay').html()
setInterval(function(){ if($('#laneconfigdisplay').html() != html){ alert('woo'); html = $('#laneconfigdisplay').html() } }, 10000) //checks your content box all 10 seconds and triggers alert when content has changed...
```

Comment: Why would you check every 10 seconds when you could just fire an event when something actually changes?

Comment: how do you know, if something changes if it does not tigger any event? I gave the answer according to the given information in the Question.

Comment: Constantly polling the DOM isn't a good idea. Changes should be reported only as and when they happen and in the context of where they happen, such as in @Shiki's 'bind' example.

Comment: +1 @dmackerman, checking for changes every x seconds doesn't make sense except in situations that *really* need it.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: @Gnagy its not for sure, but there is now other way, unless you can trigger some kind of custom event.

Answer (score 8):

Though the event [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) is deprecated, its working as of now, so for any makeshift projects you can use it as following.

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#mydiv", function() {
    alert('changed');
});
```

*In the long term though, you'll have to use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API.*

Comment: This perfectly fit for me! Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

If possible you can change the div to an textarea and use .change().

Another solution could be use a hidden textarea and update the textarea same time as you update the div. Then use .change() on the hidden textarea.

You can also use http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ to make the text area act more like a div.

```
<style>
.hidden{
display:none
}
</style>

<textarea class="hidden" rows="4" cols="50">

</textarea>


$("#hiddentextarea").change(function() {

alert('Textarea changed');

})
```

Update: It seems like textarea has to be defocused after updated, for more info: [How do I set up a listener in jQuery/javascript to monitor a if a value in the textbox has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833072/how-do-i-set-up-a-listener-in-jquery-javascript-to-monitor-a-if-a-value-in-the-t)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#D25,#E37,#E31,#F37,#E16,#E40,#F16,#F40,#E41,#F41').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved',function(){
          // your code;
       });
```

Do not use this. This may crash the page.

```
$('mydiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent [jquery plugin, **LiveQuery**, that does just this](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery).

> Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated.
>
> For example you could use the following code to bind a click event to all A tags, even any A tags you might add via AJAX.

```
$('a').livequery('click', function(event) { 
    alert('clicked'); 
    return false; 
});
```

> Once you add new A tags to your document, Live Query will bind the click event and there is nothing else that needs to be called or done.

Here is a [working example of its magic](http://codepen.io/mralexgray/pen/qaqQPy)...

[image]