# Listen for DOM appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to listen for appending or prepending a child-node in a DOM element?

Since I'm using jQuery it would be much better if a solution with their methods is provided.

Is it possible to `.delegate()`  such event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Listen to changes within a DIV and act accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712124/jquery-listen-to-changes-within-a-div-and-act-accordingly)

Comment: Please post code.. will be helful for us to help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutation events are available with the standard bind method, but as i understand IE doesn't support them.

```
$('selector').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e){
    console.log(this,arguments);
})
```

Comment: Don't use DOM mutation events with jQuery. It doesn't support them. There are some bugs (e.g. events on text nodes being rewritten to have the parent node as a target instead), and they are unwilling to accept patches since DOM mutation events are deprecated. You should use addEventListener instead. Also, recent IE versions (since 9, I think) support them.

Answer (score 1):

hope this may help you $("elementName").change();