# On textchange in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a span with a value which is asynchronously updated. so, I want jquery listen to a value and if it equals to, let's say "test" I want to hide another html element. I cannot figure out what event should I use, since [.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is only valid for textboxes and selects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Listen to changes within a DIV and act accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712124/jquery-listen-to-changes-within-a-div-and-act-accordingly)

Comment: why don't you put the logic of checking the value of span and hiding the html element in the code which sets the span value?

Comment: what causes the span to update?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the callback function of the method that's asynchronously updating the value?  If so, you can drop a conditional/listener in there that analyzes the response.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(responseData) {
      if(responseData.specificKeyValue == 'test') {
          $('element to hide').hide();
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below. Which basically triggers a custom event when you update the span.

**Note**: Below is a demo code, try to get the idea and implement accordingly.

```
$(function() {
    var $result = $('#result');
    setInterval(function() {
       $result.append('Span Updated').trigger('spanChange');
    }, 1000);

    $result.on('spanChange', function () {
        //your custom span change listener
        console.log('Span got updated');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg8L2/1/)

Comment: Now this code triggers only every second because of settimeout. How can I make it to trigger on text changed inside a div?

Comment: How do you change the text inside div? Just add a trigger like `.trigger('spanChange')` whenever you change the text inside div.

Comment: it is done by telerik controls. this was my original questions, but still cannot find solution, so i thought I can try hiding it with jquery: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/hide-radprogressarea-after-response-end.aspx

Comment: @user194076 Two things: **1.** `span` doesn't have an `onchange` event. **2.** No event will be triggered when you do it using a script (ex: `$('input').val('Test')` will not trigger `onchange` event).