# HTML select options not displaying when changed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select elements created with basic HTML:

```
                         <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
                            <select name="state"                               onchange="showLocalGovt(this.value)" class = 'validate'>
                                <option value="">Select your State</option>
                                <option value="Abia">Abia</option>
                                <option value="Adamawa">Adamawa</option>
                                <option value="Akwa Ibom">Akwa Ibom</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="state">State</label>
                        </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 16">
                            <select id="LocalGovt" name="LocalGovt" class  = 'validate'><option>Select Your Local Government</option></select>
                            <label for="LocalGovt">Select Your Local Government</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

the way this is supposed to work is , depending on the state chosen , I'm using javascript to populate the second select element.

```
function showLocalGovt(str)
```

{

```
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("LocalGovt").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var local_govts =xmlhttp.responseText.split(',');
        alert(local_govts);
        /*for(var i = 0;i<local_govts.length; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById('LocalGovt').options.add(new Option(local_govts[i], local_govts[i]));
            alert(local_govts[i]);
        }*/
        for (var i = 0; i<local_govts.length; i++){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = local_govts[i];
            opt.innerHTML = local_govts[i];
            document.getElementById('LocalGovt').appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","local_govt_db.php?state="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

The problem is the second select element doesn't get updated. I'm certain the JavaScript returns an array of the right values — I've confirmed with alerts. Also, when I use the Chrome developer tools, I can see the updated list of options. But it still doesn’t display on the webpage

Comment: Can't reproduce that -> https://jsfiddle.net/owL3pox0/

Comment: will you log the output of local_govts as comment in your question

Comment: I suppose it's just a typo in the question, but there isn't a closing brace for the `for` statement.

Comment: local_govts is an array of comma seperated values.. just like this "Select Your Local Government,Brass,Ekeremor,Kolokuma/Opokuma,Nembe,Ogbia,Sagbama,Southern Ijaw,Yenagoa"

Comment: where is your function `showLocalGovt`??

Comment: the showLocalGovt function is the function that initializes js ajax call

Comment: nothing wrong with your function. only need to clear select2 just before loop
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rizkidwip/owL3pox0/1/)

Comment: I tried that .. It's not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by re-initializing the select element with materialize because it overrides the browser's default select elements

```
    $('#LocalGovt').material_select();
```

Found my answer here:

[How to dynamically modify <select> in materialize css framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132125/how-to-dynamically-modify-select-in-materialize-css-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Need to clear 2nd select elements before loop. please try this one:

```
document.getElementById("LocalGovt").innerHTML="";    
for (var i = 0; i<local_govts.length; i++){
     ....         
}
```

Comment: I tried this .. It's not working .  the function actually works a new HTML file I created but not when I try to implement it in my project

Comment: Hi.. I found out the problem was bigger than I thought.. I'm actually unable to edit the DOM at all with js.. No element attribute can be changed.. Any help with this ?

Comment: wau, need to know a bit more about your project i guess. If possible try to open a new question if you already know the specific problem you might encounter