# Materialize select not working append option with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I use materialize css for my project, i have problem when i want to append option in matrialize select with ajax.  I've following this answer [How to dynamically modify <select> in materialize css framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132125/how-to-dynamically-modify-select-in-materialize-css-framework). but not working.

in my html i use materialize modal for render materialize form. this my code :

```
                   <div class="input-field col s12">                            
                        <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
                            <option value="1">option 1</option>
                            <option value="2">option 2Barat</option>     
                        </select>
                      <label for="select_1">Select 1</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="input-field col s12">                          
                        <select id="select_2"  name="select_2">
                            <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Choose option</option>
                        </select>
                      <label for="select_2">Select 2</label>
                    </div>
```

my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function get_selected(){
            var base_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>';
            var data = $('#select_1').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: ""+base_url+"admin/get_data/",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                data:{'data':data},
                beforeSend: function() {

                },                  
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = '';
                    var $selectDropdown = $("#select_1").empty().html(' ');

                    $.each(data, function(i, val){                      
                        $selectDropdown.append($("<option></option>").attr("value",val.id).text(val.name));

                    })

                    $selectDropdown.trigger('contentChanged');
                    $('select').on('contentChanged', function() {
                      // re-initialize (update)
                      $(this).material_select();
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                    // console.log(xhr);
                    // console.log(status);
                    // console.log(err);
                },
            });
        }


        $(document).on('change','#select_1', function(){
            get_selected();         
        })
    })
</script>
```

note : i using jquery 3.3.1 and materialize version 0.100.2. thank you for your help, sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
 });
 
 $(document).on('change','#select_1', function(){
     get_selected();         
})


function get_selected(){
     var data=[{id:1,name:"ABC"},{id:2,name:"XYZ"},{id:3,name:"PQR"}];
     
     var Options="";
    $.each(data, function(i, val){ 
      Options=Options+"<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>";
  });
  $('#select_2').empty();
  $('#select_2').append(Options);
  $("#select_2").material_select()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="row">    
<div class="input-field col s12">                            
<select id="select_1" name="select_1">
<option value="1">option 1</option>
<option value="2">option 2Barat</option>     
</select>
<label for="select_1">Select 1</label>
</div>
                    
<div class="input-field col s12">                          
<select id="select_2"  name="select_2">
<option value="0" disabled="disabled">Choose option</option>
</select>
<label for="select_2">Select 2</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this isn't an answer

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming here after 2019, please note that, the API has changed and material_Select() no longer works.
Use,

```
    $('#my_Element').append(<Array of options>)
    $('#my_Element').formSelect()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :D
do you have the background of this? Why should we use formSelect(), what is it doing?