# Dynamically load selection element with jquery/javascript showing blank

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Full Code Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPyPMZ

This is not a duplicate as that solution does not solve my problem. It works in the below snippet but not my html if you check my codepen.

I am creating a test "candidate failed ui" for users to manually select the reasons why a candidate failed. The table will be populated from an ajax request into a object that will then populate the table using insert rows. Now for each row there needs to be a selection dropdown in the next cell. Whenever I try to do this it either shows the raw code instead of the element or nothing at all.

```js
const dummy = [
  ['33333-1', 'Paul, Jake', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['81692-1', 'Smith, Ted', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['82654-1', 'Rele, Don', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['32984-1', 'Titan, Angela', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['33333-1', 'Paul, Jake', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['81692-1', 'Smith, Ted', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['82654-1', 'Rele, Don', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['32984-1', 'Titan, Angela', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['33333-1', 'Paul, Jake', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['81692-1', 'Smith, Ted', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['82654-1', 'Rele, Don', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['32984-1', 'Titan, Angela', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['33333-1', 'Paul, Jake', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['81692-1', 'Smith, Ted', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['82654-1', 'Rele, Don', 'Mitchell, Nuna'],
  ['32984-1', 'Titan, Angela', 'Mitchell, Nuna']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableRef = document
    .getElementById('data')
    .getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  $('#sub').click(function() {
    //alert($('#pcowner :selected').text());
    $('#dataRows').empty();
    dummy.forEach(row => {
      try {
        let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(
          tableRef.rows.length
        );
        let newC0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        let newC1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        let newC2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        let newC3 = newRow.insertCell(3);
        let newT0 = document.createTextNode(row[0]);
        let newT1 = document.createTextNode(row[1]);
        let newT2 = document.createTextNode(row[2]);
        let newT3 = document.createElement('div');
        let html =
          '<select><option value="">Pick me</option></select>';
        newT3.innerHTML = html;
        newC0.appendChild(newT0);
        newC1.appendChild(newT1);
        newC2.appendChild(newT2);
        newC3.append(newT3);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="sub" name="action" style="margin-top:17px;float:left;" type="submit">Refresh
  </button>
<div class="customContainer">
  <table class="highlight responsive-table" id="data">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="headers">Request ID</th>
        <th class="headers">Candidate Name</th>
        <th class="headers">Engagment Manager</th>
        <th class="headers">Fail Classification</th>
        <th class="headers">Reason</th>
        <th class="headers">Comments</th>
        <th class="headers">PC Action Required</th>
        <th class="headers">PM Action Required</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataRows"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

For additional challenge, both fail classification and reasons are dropdowns with relations to each other.

```
const failClassifications = [1, 2, 3]
const failReasons = {"1":["Late","Never Showed"],"2":["Background Failed"],"3":["Excessive pay request", "pours milk before cereal"]}
```

Based on what selection made in fail classification it will populate the next column with the appropriate dropdown selections.

Comment: You have jQuery, why not use it?

Comment: `newC3.innerHTML=html;` works

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: I've tried doing that, but it stills shows blank. newC3.innerHTML still does not work, could you post a png?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2ZpgauR - also you used append, not appendChild

Comment: And if you need to populate other fields onchange of the inserted select, please search for jquery delegate

Comment: @mplungjan I've made all the edits you proposed to no resolve, can you check my codepen. I know it works in the snippet but for some reason it wont show on the broswer. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPyPMZ

Comment: You are using Materialize so you need to refresh the plugin when you change the DOM

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762398/materialize-select-not-working-append-option-with

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for