# Set options text (that is displayed to users) of <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-select

I created a dialog with `<select>` dropdown on Google sheets.
I used this [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/select.html) framework code for select.
The dropdown has to show my dynamically updated data.

I call the function from backend to get my data **to show it in select options as text** that people see in dropdown, user's text.

But the data is not showing visible to the eye in a dropdown (see the screenshot of white options below).

In a dropdown I get the options in white with no color and when I click on them only then I can see my data shown in a row as a chosen variant.

In other words, you don't see what you choose even thought everithing in on the right place.

I need **to add data to the visible dropdown selection so you can see what you choose.**

I was trying to add it as an options object ({}) as mentions on the framework site, but it didn't work with me.

Appreciate any help.

The code:

```js
    //on loading DOM select initialization, run my function
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var options = addWeeks()
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
        });

    function addWeeks() {
        //get data from backend and pass it to changeOptions function as arguments
        var weeks = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeOptions).calculateWeeks()

        return weeks
     }

        function changeOptions(weeks) {


        var week1 = document.getElementById("1week").text = weeks[0]
        var week2 = document.getElementById("2week").text = weeks[1]
        var week3 = document.getElementById("3week").text = weeks[2]  

        var weeksTexts = {1: week1, 2: week2, 3: week3}

        return weeksTexts
    }
```

```html
  <select>  
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose week</option>
  <option value="1week" id ="1week" ></option>
  <option value="2week" id ="2week" ></option>
  <option value="3week" id ="3week" ></option>
  </select>
```

[image]

Comment: `textContent` is the way to go.

Comment: textContent and innerHTML both don't work with me, nothing changes. updated with the screenshot of how my dropdown looks.

Comment: Actually, `text` is fine for an `option` element. Clicking Run code snippet doesn't do much here because it's not in a Google App context. When I remove the code `google.`* it seems to work fine. I do see that you don't call `changeOptions` anywhere in your code. Perhaps that's it/

Comment: This line calls it: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(changeOptions).calculateWeeks()

Comment: Are you sure it's being called? I'd put a `console.log('changeOptions')` within the function and see if it shows up... Also, that doesn't look like a standard drop-down; it may be that you have to have the text in the options before it's rendered...

Comment: If you ever want more than one drop down list, and want to get a specific list, then I wouldn't use `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');`  And I wouldn't give every option an id, because you might want dynamic lists with different numbers of options.  You can add options one at a time, or get all the options and loop through them.  The value is the same as the ID, so you don't need the ID in order to know what option was choosen.   In an option list, the value can be different than the text content.  For example: `<option value="1week" id ="wk1" >Week One</option>`

Comment: The use `google.script.run` makes the code to be no executable and in such case Stack Snippet should not be use.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's called as I get data from there. When I click white options the text appears then. Here's how it's been called https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)

Comment: @Rubén where do I need to put my code instead?

Comment: @kiki instead of using Stack Snippet for Google Apps Script code use the other code formatting options described at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was to add to the select tag this class: "browser-default".

It cancelled the conversion of the select element to ul element that Materializecss framework does.

So with the code above I pass values dynamically now.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle - Add options dynamically](https://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/dz7cyew1/2/)

I would add an id to the select tag, and not give the options elements an ID attribute. If you are adding options to the select tag with code, then you don't need to enter pre-existing options tag html

```
<select id="idWkChoice"><!-- select tag with only the first option -->
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose week</option>
</select>
```

Get the select element, which contains all the options as children.

```
var slctTagWeeks = document.getElementById('idWkChoice');//Get drop down element
```

Add options to the list:

```
var slctTagWeeks = document.getElementById('idWkChoice');//Get drop down element
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Week 1";
option.value = "wk1";//Add a value code that is different than the show text
slctTagWeeks.add(option);
```

The above code adds an option to the list that didn't exist before.

Then you could create a loop, and add the number of options in the list:

```
var option;
var slctTagWeeks = document.getElementById('idWkChoice');//Get drop down element

var weeks = {
  wk1:'Week One',
  wk2:'Week Two',
  wk3:'Week Three'
}

for (var k in weeks) {
  thisID = k;
  thisText = weeks[k];
  option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = thisText;
  option.value = thisID;//Add a value code that is different than the show text
  slctTagWeeks.add(option);

}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work with me. Is it possible to create options dynamically at all?

Comment: The data in the `weeks` object needs to be structured a certain way.  I've created a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/dz7cyew1/2/) that adds options to the list.  The js fiddle runs when the page load.  In the js fiddle example, the values for `weeks` object is hard coded.  That's just to provide an example.  So, the js fiddle proves that it works.  But the data coming back from the server either needs to be in the format of the object, or if the data isn't in an object, you can change the data structure.  So, "yes" it's possible to dynamically add options to the list.

Comment: thank you, Alan. The fiddle works well. I changed (even hardcoded) my weeks from an array to an object and it's not working still. Don't get what's wrong. Can somebosy correct my client'server communication code?

Comment: How can I scustomize it when using this select?  https://materializecss.com/select.html Maybe it has somehing to do with this framework. In fiddle it wotks, on practice doesn't.

Comment: On that materializecss page for the drop downs, I inspected the html from the browser developer tools, and the materilizecss drop down list is actually an un-ordered list `<ul><li></li></ul>`  sitting underneath an input field.  So, if that's the case, then the code I provided is not going to work.  I don't know how materilizecss works.  Does the markup html code get converted to something else?  I don't know.  I searched for information about how to update a materializecss drop down, but didn't find anything.  Right click the drop down and choose "inspect" and look at the actual html.

Comment: Alan, agree with you on that framework. And thank you for your contrubutions! I guess I can try other frameworks or something. If someone knows the solution I a ppreciate your advice.

Comment: There are many material design frameworks to choose from.  I have my own opinion, but don't want to state it here.  People have different requirements and preferences.  I looked at the Materialize docs some more, and they do have methods and properties that can be used on the select element.  There are only two methods, `.getSelectedValues()` and `.destroy()`  There is nothing for setting options.  I did find the following StackOverflow post:  [How to dynamically modify <select> in materialize css framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879519/2946873)