# Rails best way to initialize function in Javascript after ajax and document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The question is that there are some functions that I call to initial some elements on the page. But after ajax success, I have to re-call those functions again and again in multiple places. I was wondering beside using the following combo

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function A
 }); 

 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   function A
 });
```

I read that there are something I can do with the setTimeout and clock up the thread to delay the function call from the link http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/07/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-using.html
but I have a hard time digesting it. If someone can break it down for me.

Update:

I meant that when I do an html updated inside multiple ajax success, I have to call function A to re initialize and the code above is my idea but I think there should be a better way

Example

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'some url',
    data: data, 
    success: function(data) {
      $('#some-sector').html(data);
      function A;   <------- to init
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'b', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'another url',
    data: data, 
    success: function(data) {
      $('#some-sector').html(data);
      function A;   <------- to init
    }
  });
});
```

Another Update:

So Basically there are some elements on the page that I need to update dynamically by calling function A. And from the example, I have multiple ajax that updates a page. Instead of calling function A in multiple the ajax success, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. The only thing that i could think of it's the top code.

Comment: I have read your question 3 times and I still don't know what you want. Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: See the latest update ... see if that make sense

Comment: Alright, checkout that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960919/jquery-watch-for-domelement-changes), You basically want some kind of a watcher if the element changes?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you are calling some group of functions on DOM ready
function as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function_01();
function_02();
function_03();
});
```

and want to call the same function on the ajax request

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
function_01();
function_02();
function_03();
});
```

You can define a common function that call internally all the functions that are in need

```
function callAll()
{
function_01();
function_02();
function_03();
}
```

and then call as the following

```
$(document).ready(callAll);

$(document).ajaxComplete(callAll);
```

at what logic you want to cal this **callAll** method again and again..

**update**

try calling the function as below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function callall()
        {
            alert("call all");
        }
        $(document).ajaxComplete(callall);
  });
```

and this will call the initialize function after the ajax request is processed

Hope it helps...........