# Run function when element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

A few things I've read have led me to the `ready()` function, but that seems to run as soon as the document itself is ready, regardless of what element you actually call it on.  For example, I'm used to running things when the page is loaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.alert("foo");
});
```

What I'm trying to do is run a script when an element with a certain is loaded.  That element is added to the page dynamically, and not when the page is initially loaded.  I've tried this:

```
$("#element-id").ready(function() {
  window.alert("foo");
});
```

But that runs on page load, regardless of what id I pass in.  Whether or not an element with the passed in id exists on the page or not, or is loaded dynamically, the function always runs on page load, and never again.

How do I tell jquery to run a function when an element is loaded? I'm using jQuery 2.1.4.

Comment: Since you load the element dynamically, can't you just call your function after that?

Comment: How are you adding the element, please show enough [mcve] code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm not actually loading the element myself.  I'm writing a plugin for bitbucket, and trying to run some javascript when the edit pull request dialog is loaded.

Comment: Maybe somethign like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960919/jquery-watch-for-domelement-changes ?

Comment: You would have to watch the dom then like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener) and check if the changes reflect your element being added

Comment: There is nothing built into jQuery core that does what you want....'\

Comment: The `.ready()` event ignores the element, it's always for the document.

Comment: Usually DOMs in static html file are loaded synchronously, while images inside DOMs are loaded asynchronously, you may notice when you try to open a web page on slow internet, the text will loaded first then slowly the images are loaded. So you might need certain images loaded inside the element.