# Run js function when a tag is created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a plugin for a website, where I create a couple of table-rows and they get injected into an already existing table on the website.

My table-rows will get created when a button is pressed, however I have no access to this button since it's already on the website, not in my plugin.

Is it possible for me to create a JS function that runs when my table-rows are created?

Comment: Just try, try, try, try, try ....... if it fails, show us what you have tried

Comment: Maybe you can use what in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845549/10153945
It detect a change in the DOM using jquery

Comment: @jonatjano that solution worked, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event when element added to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434685/event-when-element-added-to-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming my comment as an answer for future viewer to see :

> Maybe you can use what in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845549/10153945 It detect a change in the DOM using jquery

in this answer [courtney christensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311207/courtney-christensen) propose to use `jQuery`'s `DOMSubtreeModified` to detect changes

```
$('#content').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e) {
  if (e.target.innerHTML.length > 0) {
    // Content change handler
  }
});
```

Look at his answer and upvote him too ; )

Comment: The same can be done without jQuery : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659678/10153945